# Sparql 1.1 get all the instances of a specific classes, but do not include any instances from subclasses

Tags: sparql, owl

I am creating a class hierarchy based on RDFS/OWL, and creating instances in all the classes using the `a` (`rdf:type`) relationship. I want to retrieve instances of a specific class, not including the instances of its children. However, when I write a SPARQL query, it gives me all the instances of every child class as well.

My ontology says:

`Book` is a class, which has two subclasses: `hard_bounded_book` and `soft_binded_books`

In other words (with some instances):

```
@prefix ex:    <http://book_triples.org/> .
@prefix rdf:   <http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#> .
@prefix rdfs:  <http://www.w3.org/2000/01/rdf-schema#> .

ex:hard_bounded_book1
        a       ex:hard_bounded_book .
ex:soft_binded_books1a
        a       ex:soft_binded_books .
ex:soft_binded_books  rdfs:subClassOf  ex:Book .
ex:hard_bounded_book  rdfs:subClassOf  ex:Book .
ex:Book  a      rdf:Class .
ex:Book1  a     ex:Book .
```

when I query

```
PREFIX  rdf:  <http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#>
PREFIX  ex:  <http://book_triples.org/>
SELECT  ?book
WHERE
  { ?book  rdf:type  ex:Book }
```

It returns all three `Book1`, `hard_bounded_book1`, `soft_binded_books1`, but I would like to get only the first result (`Book1`).

Any help is appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: Which API or triple store do you use?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Regardless of whether inferencing is turned on or off in your store, you can write a query that only returns the instances of the specific class, by
filtering out all the instances that are also instances of a subclass of `ex:Book`, like so:

```
SELECT  ?book
WHERE { 
  ?book  rdf:type  ex:Book 
  FILTER NOT EXISTS { 
     ?book rdf:type ?c . 
     ?c rdfs:subClassOf+ ex:Book .
     FILTER (?c != ex:Book)  
}
```

It checks that for every book returned, a triple making that book an instance of a subclass of `ex:Book` does not exist.  The second filter (checking that `?c` is not equal to `ex:Book`) is necessary because in RDFS, every class is a subclass of itself.

Of course, this query is more expensive to run than the simple original you had, so if your triplestore has an option to (temporarily) turn off inferencing, that might be a preferable solution.

As an aside: the `+` sign behind the `subClassOf` pattern is a "1 or more levels deep" operator, and is optional here. You need to include it if you wish to be rigorous about excluding *all* possible instances of subclasses, even if the reasoner has completed all inferences. Given that in your scenario it's likely there's a reasoner that infers the complete deductive closure, you can probably leave it out.

**Update** To explain in a bit more detail my point about the `+` sign: imagine that we have classes A, B, and C: B is a subclass of A, and C is a subclass of B.

Imagine an individual x, which is declared to be an instance of C.

1. *without* inferencing, any query for all instances of A will not return x, regardless of whether we filter out subclasses in the query.
2. *with* inferencing, x will be inferred to be of type B, and of type A, so the subclass-filter without the `+` sign will work to remove x from the 
   result.

So far so good. *However*, imagine that we also insert the explicit fact that x is an instance of A.

If inferencing is enabled, we're still fine with the query without a `+` operator. However, *without* inferencing, the query for all instances of A will now return x, even though x is also an instance of an (indirect) subclass of A (namely, C). That is the edge case for which the `+` operator is helpful.

Comment: Thank you. This solves the problem. 2 questions along the lines: Is there any way to turnoff the inferencing, temporarily while quering. If I dont use + sign, would it ignore the immediate subclasses and thus all the subsequent subclasses. is + sign really needed?

Comment: Question 1: that depends on which triplestore you're using. Question 2: I'll edit the answer to quickly sketch why it might be necessary.

Comment: Got it. Thanks again.

Answer (score 1):

I edited your question to provide a well-formed input and query.  Have I misrepresented anything?

**I really suspect this is an inference or reasoning issue.**  What triplestore are you using?  Do you know whether reasoning is enabled?

When I insert your triples into Blazegraph, with `inference` turned `off`, and run your query, I get the desired result:

```
+----------------------------------------------+
|                     book                     |
+----------------------------------------------+
| <http://book_triples.org/Book1>              |
+----------------------------------------------+
```

When I turn inference on, I get the result you describe:

```
+----------------------------------------------+
|                     book                     |
+----------------------------------------------+
| <http://book_triples.org/Book1>              |
| <http://book_triples.org/hard_bounded_book1> |
| <http://book_triples.org/soft_binded_books1> |
+----------------------------------------------+
```